# Are there any (exponential) families without a minimal sufficient statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dimensionality-reduction, sufficient-statistics, frequentist, decision-theory

Bahadur's theorem says that ***if a minimal sufficient statistic exists***, then a complete sufficient statistic is also minimal sufficient.
Are there any (homogenous, identifiable) families with a complete sufficient statistic but no minimal sufficient statistic?

A more restricted question:

An exponential family under its natural parameterization is guaranteed to have a complete sufficient statistic (Theorem 2.8 of Li, Babu). But does it necessarily contain a minimal sufficient statistic?

A closely related question: I notice a version of Bahadur’s theorem claims a finite dimensional real bounded-complete sufficient statistic $T$ is minimal sufficient.
A proof of this version is here: [1](https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/Statistical%20inference/Lecture5.pdf)
Where is the finite dimensionality used in the proof and what can go wrong if it isn’t there? Looks to me like it works with $T$ with countably infinite entries also.

Comment: Given the last paragraph, it would seem such a family must be exceptionally poorly behaved.